# LDAP Breaking when moving user

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Since I've been working at this company we've had a very basic AD setup. Users go in the user CN and there is a few OUs for computers, like desktops and servers.

Recently I've been planning a more comprehensive design to allow for custom department GP settings (specifically printers). I want to move users into OU's created for each department. Everything seemed to be working fine based on my testing except for one application.

JReport is a reporting application that has a LDAP setup to import users. It then implements SSO using that info. Been working great with our current settings, but the second I move a user from CN=Users to OU=XYZ they can no longer authenticate.

Here is a screenshot of the settings for the application:
[image: Settings]

As you can see it is a pretty simple setup. If I test the connection the directory manager has access. If I query users I can see the users that are in the new OU. But if I try to access a report it doesn't work. Even if I enter in the credentials manually.

So I guess my question is can anyone think of any reason that moving a user to a new OU would break this?

Comment: `I want to move users into OU's created for each department` - I don't know your organization, but this simply won't work at many orgs I support.  There is almost never a perfect one-to-one mapping of people to departments/programs/etc.  I strongly suggest you consider the the **G** in GP stands for **GROUP**.  Trying to use OUs as a grouping mechanism will result in really ugly policies.

Comment: No doubt. I have run into a few people that don't really fit.
I could probably just have everyone in a high level OU, like how some places make one for each location. But I am primarily sorted them for printer reasons. Almost all settings will be done on a high level GP.

I do see the merit to your suggestion though. I could use item level targeting and just hit groups instead. Kind of a moot point now though as it is all done and seems to be working fine. But I will keep it in mind for the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sniff the LDAP traffic during an attempted authentication to see what it's actually doing. That's the best way to figure it out.

I'll go out on a limb and speculate a bit. Since you talk about it "importing" users I wonder if it isn't maintaining some persistent record of the user's old DN and, when you move the user, the new DN isn't being queried during the authentication process.

Comment: I think you might be right. I just tested deleting and re-adding my account and it worked. Gonna test some more. Thanks

Comment: Tried it on several more accounts and that was it. Just needed to delete the imported accounts, re-import the LDAP data and re-add the users. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Are groups being moved out of the users CN as well?

I'm not sure what the `cn=users` thing under `Group Schema` would be doing in context of the field mapping and filtering that it's supposed to be doing.. but maybe it's a base DN for groups relative to the global base DN ("Root Entry") that is set for the directory?

It would make more sense as an attribute mapping, in which case it ought to be `distinguishedName` (and while we're at it, "Group Member Type" ought to be `member` if I'm interpreting their wording correctly).

Try blanking the group distinguished name on the assumption that it's a base DN and see if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: Yes, their LDAP setup is not very clear and the documentation leaves a lot to be desired. From what I can tell the Group Schema isn't even needed.

I did want to set it to distinguishedName as that seems to be the way Microsoft is going. However, this application only really supports old specs despite being "up to date" software. So it didn't really seem to be working. Thanks for the suggestions.